# How to authenticate a web application using Apache syncope?

Tags: authentication, apache-syncope

I am trying to use Apache syncope for authentication in my web application.

Can anyone tell me the steps to do that.

Till now I have completed the installation. Syncope, Syncope-console and Syncope-enduser applications are up and running in tomcat server.

Answer (score 1):

The approach for Apache Syncope 2.0.2 is this:

1. Register user (either through POST http://admin@pass/syncope/rest/users, sending JSON UserTO, etc.) or Self-register (more or less the same but, users/self, and must be anonymous (no admin@pass).  This will get you UserTO with KEY for use in other API.
2. Once registered, use GET with users/self, including Basic Http Auth user+password.  (curl -u user:pass  can be used as example.)  This will get you a UserTO with key that can be used in other API's.
3. Save UserTO in Session and proceed as authenticated.  Entitlements will be included.

Take a look at the Swagger UI or JSON (http://:/syncope/swagger || syncope/rest/swagger.json for details.

I recommend swagger-client NPM package for working with this REST api.